# Harmonic polynomial

Tags: analysis

I am working on a project regarding the number of zeros of a harmonic polynomial and am stuck with the proof of this: The zero set of the harmonic polynomial  h(z)= $z^n$ - $\bar{z}^n$ consists of n equally spaced lines through the origin. 
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to write $z = re^{i \theta}$ with $r, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$; this should help.

Answer (score 2):

if $z=re^{i\theta}$ then this reduces to $e^{2ni\theta}=1$.  the solutions to this are $\theta=\pi k/n$.  so the lines $\{re^{k\pi i/n} : r\in(-\infty,\infty)\}, k=0,1,...n-1$ are the zero set.

Comment: Hi yoyo, thanks for breaking it down. For some reason, the modulus and phase conversion didn't strike me. Thanks again.